# Vim: Is there a way to replace all occurrences of a word without typing it?

Tags: vim

I have the following code:

```
  long_word: ISubscription['long_word'];
```

This is what I normally do:

```
shift v
:s/long_word/new_word/g
```

It's tedious to have to type the word I'm trying to replace. So sometimes I just do

```
ciw
new_word
esc
$
hhhh
.
```

which feels inefficient.

Is there a way to do something like `ciw` but on the whole line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+word+under+cursor+command+line

Answer (score 2):

First things first: `V` is not necessary because the default range for `:help :s` is the current line. So that's one improvement.

Then there is the unavoidable fact that the string to substitute has to be defined, somehow. You can't just have your cursor anywhere on the line and expect Vim to figure it out on its own. The only way to start the process is to literally *point* Vim at the string in question… by placing your cursor on it.

So, assuming the string to substitute is under your cursor and matches Vim's definition of a `word` (see `:help word`), you can use `:help c_ctrl-r_ctrl-w` to insert it in the command-line:

```
:s/<C-r><C-w>/new-word/g<CR>
```

If you have to do that often, you could save yourself a lot of effort with a simple mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>//g<Left><Left>
```

[image: sub]

Note the `\<` and `\>`, which makes sure that only whole words are matched.

Now, the string to substitute might not be a `word` (or a `WORD`, in which case you would use `:help c_ctrl-r_ctrl-a`). In that case, you can still visually select it, yank it, and insert it in the command-line:

```
v{motion}
y
:s/<C-r>"/new-word/g<CR>
```

which, of course, could also be turned into a mapping:

```
xnoremap <key> y:s/<C-r>"//g<Left><Left>
```

[image: sub2]

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
:s/short-string/new_word
```

to set the replacement pattern, then put the cursor on `long_word` and type `*` or `#` to set the search pattern, and then do:

```
g&
```

to replace all occurrences of `long_word` with `new_word`.  It's not super elegant, but it's not terrible.

Make sure `short-string` is easy to type and not actually a string that occurs on the current line (you don't actually want to replace it!). I find `short-string` usually ends up being something like `kjkjkjj`.  Not elegant, but effective.

Comment: You could simplify that with `*` or `#`, followed by `:s//new_word/g`.